# Encoding program in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am currently working on an encoding program in prolog.

In the first place I want to cut a word in pieces

For example: friends should look like:

```
[[F,R,I][R,I,E][I,E,N][E,N,D][N,D,S]]
```

For the moment I have something like this but can't understand why is the program not working when I try on a word.

It is always answering false.

```
couper([X1,X2,X3|L],[L1|ResQ]):-
    L1 = [X1,X2,X3],
    couper([X2,X3|L],ResQ).

couper([_,_|[]] , []).
couper([]       , []).
couper([_|[]]   , []).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program seems to work:

```
?- atom_chars(alpha,L),couper(L,Triplets).

L = [a, l, p, h, a],
Triplets = [[a, l, p], [l, p, h], [p, h, a]] ;
```

Although it can be written easier:

```
couper([X1,X2,X3|L],[[X1,X2,X3]|ResQ]):-
    couper([X2,X3|L],ResQ).

couper([_,_] , []).  % Only two chars left or only two to begin with
couper([_]   , []).  % Only one char to begin with
couper([]    , []).  % No chars to begin with
```

Comment: same here. it works. can you give an example question where you get an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
?- findall([A,B,C], append(_,[A,B,C|_],[f,r,i,e,n,d,s]), T).
T = [[f, r, i], [r, i, e], [i, e, n], [e, n, d], [n, d, s]].
```

As a rule:

```
couper(L, T) :-
   findall([A,B,C], append(_, [A,B,C|_], L), T).
```

Examples:

```
?- couper([f,r,i,e,n,d,s], T).
T = [[f, r, i], [r, i, e], [i, e, n], [e, n, d], [n, d, s]].

?- couper([e,x,a,m,p,l,e,s], T).
T = [[e, x, a], [x, a, m], [a, m, p], [m, p, l], [p, l, e], [l, e, s]].

?- couper([t,w,o], T).
T = [[t, w, o]].

?- couper([t,o], T).
T = [].
```

**NOTE** In Prolog, uppercase letters are variables. Thus, the predicate must be called with a list of lowercase letters (perhaps, this is the cause of your problem).